# how do i find 3 even nums in a dynamic range and its avg

Tags: excel, vba

i have this vba- excel problem im stuck on for days , i can really use some help.

i have a  numbers table within a dynamic range (different for every time a button is beeing prresed.) the table is spread along the entire range..
and i need within that tables  to find three numbers who are :

1. even
2. the avg of those 3 nums is one of them (of the nums)

after finding that trio , i need to color them in the table and print a msgbox who states the areas boundris ( 4X3 for example..) and the fact that this trio exists and also the num who is the avg.

im only having a problem with finding that trio and somehow store it.
any kind of help will be great.

this is what i have so far :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
x = rng.Rows.Count
y = rng.Columns.Count

For Each cell In rng
  If Not (cell.Value Mod 2 = 0) Then cell.Value = ""
    Next cell
    
    For Each cell In rng
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        
        If Cells(i, j) - cell.Value = Abs(cell.Value - Cells(i, j)) Then
           
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                MsgBox "the area is" & "" & x & "X" & y & vbNewLine & "there are 3 special nums" & vbNewLine & "avarege is " & "" & cell.Value
                End If
                Next j
                Next i
                Next cell
                
                 
                 MsgBox "the area is" & "" & x & "X" & y & vbNewLine & "there are no speacial nums"
                 
                 End Sub
```

the range can not be more then a few rows or coulmns. also , the trio can be anywhere in the table . the idea is to recognzie the trio that meet the mentiond requirements.

[image]

Comment: could you maybe show an example screenshot of a selected range? Would help a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are those even numbers in same row or just in same selection? Could be more than 1 trio inside the same range? An example of your input and expected output would be really useful. Consider that, depending on conditions, as example, inside a 9 different numbers group, you can make up to 84 different trios... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination IF your dataset is really large, maybe Excel is not the right approach

Comment: @aylon21342 Please, [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71436724/edit) your original question and post an example

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns just did

Comment: 42 elements in trios implies around 11480 different combinatios. ¿Can be more than one solution in same group? ¿Or you need just to find 1 and quit¿ ¿Do you need to find them all?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns there is only one soulotion for every time we press the fill area button. we press the fill area button then we find only one trio that meet the demands (if there is one ) and then we msgbox the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best approach would be to get rid first of odd values and then ignoring duplicated data and then try trios of remaining numbers. Anyways, please, notice that depending on how many different values you got, performance can be affected.

Also, notice that because your data got duplicates, sometimes you could get highlited more than 3 cells.

Be sure your activecell is inside the range to check for this code to work!

Before code:

[image]

After code:

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim MyNumbers() As Double
Dim Dict As Object
Dim MyKey As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long



Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'this will work based on active cell. It will take complete region

For Each rng In ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
    'get rid of odd elements
    If Dict.Exists(rng.Value) = False And rng.Value / 2 = Int(rng.Value / 2) Then Dict.Add rng.Value, 0
Next rng

ReDim MyNumbers(1 To Dict.Count)

i = 1
For Each MyKey In Dict.Keys
    MyNumbers(i) = MyKey
    i = i + 1
Next MyKey

Dict.RemoveAll


For i = 1 To UBound(MyNumbers) - 2 Step 1
    For j = (i + 1) To UBound(MyNumbers) - 1 Step 1
        For k = (j + 1) To UBound(MyNumbers) Step 1
            If (MyNumbers(i) + MyNumbers(j) + MyNumbers(k)) / 3 = MyNumbers(i) Or _
            (MyNumbers(i) + MyNumbers(j) + MyNumbers(k)) / 3 = MyNumbers(j) Or _
            (MyNumbers(i) + MyNumbers(j) + MyNumbers(k)) / 3 = MyNumbers(k) Then
                'there is a match, we save that part
                Dict.Add MyNumbers(i), 0
                Dict.Add MyNumbers(j), 0
                Dict.Add MyNumbers(k), 0
                MsgBox "There is a match." & vbNewLine & "Area is " & ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count & "x" & ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
                GoTo Result
            End If
            
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

'there is no match
MsgBox "There is a match." & vbNewLine & "Area is " & ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count & "x" & ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
GoTo Final

Result:
For Each rng In ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
    'highlight numbers in dict
    If Dict.Exists(rng.Value) = True Then rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow
Next rng

Final:
Erase MyNumbers
Set Dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thanx man. actually im not allowed to use dictaniory for this drill but i get the ideas used here , so thank you for youre time. and if you have any other ideas regarding a soulotion without a dictionary , ill be more then intreseted to know them.

Comment: What do you mean you are not allowed to use dictionaries?